# Windows service logon correctly, but it can not access the shared network folder

Tags: windows, windows-services

I have a service ALOADER which constantly accesses a shared network folder \\10.10.1.100.

Before starting the service ALOADER, i have to make the \\10.10.1.100 visible to the service ALOADER.

The problem is that, the access account of \\10.10.1.100 could not be logged on the service ALOADER, since the \\10.10.1.100 and the server running ALOADER are in different domains.

Instead, I use the "net use \\10.10.1.100" with a local account, and then log on that local account to the service ALOADER.

It works on some servers, but not the others. (the \\10.10.1.100 is accessible on Explorer, but not on the service.)

All the server settings are similar, and the OS is Windows Server 2008 R2.

Looking for your help.

Sincerely, 
Jun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your service you should call [NetUseAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370645%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to connect to the network share.